# Fetch CSV file into PANDAS and send report of Spotify statistics

Tags: python, parsing, csv, pandas, email

I'm relatively new and self taught in Python. I've written this code which gets a CSV file from a website, plays around with the data then creates an email with information gleaned.

I know this is too long and clunky, I'm just not sure how to bring it down. Not looking for exact code from you, rather a nudge in the right direction that I can go and research/learn myself. For example, can I use a for loop to build the variables and/or email sends.

Any help greatly appreciated!

```
### Open website to click CSV

import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
date_string = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
url = ("https://app.chartmetric.com/charts/spotify_legacy#chartType=spotify_daily_top&country=nz&date=" + date_string)

webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open(url)

input("Download CSV then press 'Enter' to continue...")

### Convert to excel and move

from pyexcel.cookbook import merge_all_to_a_book
import glob
import shutil
import os

merge_all_to_a_book(glob.glob("//Downloads/Spotify Daily Top 200.csv"), ("//Daily Song Spikes/spotify_daily_spikes.xlsx"))
time.sleep(2)
os.remove("//Downloads/Spotify Daily Top 200.csv")

### Parse Data

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("//Daily Song Spikes/spotify_daily_spikes.xlsx", sheet_name='Spotify Daily Top 200.csv')

df["Release Date"] = df["Release Date"].str.split(', ').str[1]
df.loc[df["Change"] == "New", "Change"] = 99999
df = df[(df['Streams']>=7000) & (df['Change']>=5) & (df['Release Date']<="2021") & (df['Rank']<=100)] 

df.drop(axis=1, labels="Label", inplace=True)
df.drop(axis=1, labels="Internal Link", inplace=True)
df.drop(axis=1, labels="Album", inplace=True)
df.drop(axis=1, labels="7-Day Velocity", inplace=True)
df.drop(axis=1, labels="ISRC", inplace=True)

df.to_excel('spotify_daily_spikes.xlsx', sheet_name='Filtered Data')

print(len(df.index), "songs returned")

value = input("How many songs to send: ",)

if value == "1":
  artist1 = df.iloc[0,4]
  song1 = df.iloc[0,2]
  change1 = df.iloc[0,1]
  link1 = df.iloc[0,3]
  streams1 = df.iloc[0,6]
  year1 = df.iloc[0,5]
  rank1 = df.iloc[0,0]

### Send email

  def spotifydailyspike(text, subject, recipient):
    import win32com.client as win32   
    import os

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    mail.Display(True)



  MailSubject = "Spotify Daily Spike"
  MailAdress =""
  MailInput =  """\
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <h1 style="font-family:calibri;font-size:30px">TODAY'S SPIKEY SONGS</h1>
    <i><h4 style="font-family:calibri-light;font-size:12px;color:red">THIS IS AN AUTOMATED EMAIL</h4></i>
        <p style="font-family:calibri light">
       """ +str(artist1)+ """ - <a href=""" +link1+ """>""" +str(song1)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year1)+ """. """ +str(streams1)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change1)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank1)+ """<br>

      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
  """
     
   
  spotifydailyspike(MailInput, MailSubject, MailAdress)
  

elif value == "2":
  artist1 = df.iloc[0,4]
  song1 = df.iloc[0,2]
  change1 = df.iloc[0,1]
  link1 = df.iloc[0,3]
  streams1 = df.iloc[0,6]
  year1 = df.iloc[0,5]
  rank1 = df.iloc[0,0]

  artist2 = df.iloc[1,4]
  song2 = df.iloc[1,2]
  change2 = df.iloc[1,1]
  link2 = df.iloc[1,3]
  streams2 = df.iloc[1,6]
  year2 = df.iloc[1,5]
  rank2 = df.iloc[1,0]

  def spotifydailyspike(text, subject, recipient):
    import win32com.client as win32   
    import os

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    mail.Display(True)



  MailSubject = "Spotify Daily Spike"
  MailAdress =""
  MailInput =  """\
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <h1 style="font-family:calibri;font-size:30px">TODAY'S SPIKEY SONGS</h1>
    <i><h4 style="font-family:calibri-light;font-size:12px;color:red">THIS IS AN AUTOMATED EMAIL</h4></i>
        <p style="font-family:calibri light">
       """ +str(artist1)+ """ - <a href=""" +link1+ """>""" +str(song1)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year1)+ """. """ +str(streams1)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change1)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank1)+ """<br>
       """ +str(artist2)+ """ - <a href=""" +link2+ """>""" +str(song2)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year2)+ """. """ +str(streams2)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change2)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank2)+ """<br>

      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
  """
     
   
  spotifydailyspike(MailInput, MailSubject, MailAdress)


elif value == "3":
  artist1 = df.iloc[0,4]
  song1 = df.iloc[0,2]
  change1 = df.iloc[0,1]
  link1 = df.iloc[0,3]
  streams1 = df.iloc[0,6]
  year1 = df.iloc[0,5]
  rank1 = df.iloc[0,0]

  artist2 = df.iloc[1,4]
  song2 = df.iloc[1,2]
  change2 = df.iloc[1,1]
  link2 = df.iloc[1,3]
  streams2 = df.iloc[1,6]
  year2 = df.iloc[1,5]
  rank2 = df.iloc[1,0]
 
  artist3 = df.iloc[2,4]
  song3 = df.iloc[2,2]
  change3 = df.iloc[2,1]
  link3 = df.iloc[2,3]
  streams3 = df.iloc[2,6]
  year3 = df.iloc[2,5]
  rank3 = df.iloc[2,0]

  def spotifydailyspike(text, subject, recipient):
    import win32com.client as win32   
    import os

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    mail.Display(True)



  MailSubject = "Spotify Daily Spike"
  MailAdress =""
  MailInput =  """\
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <h1 style="font-family:calibri;font-size:30px">TODAY'S SPIKEY SONGS</h1>
    <i><h4 style="font-family:calibri-light;font-size:12px;color:red">THIS IS AN AUTOMATED EMAIL</h4></i>
        <p style="font-family:calibri light">
     """ +str(artist1)+ """ - <a href=""" +link1+ """>""" +str(song1)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year1)+ """. """ +str(streams1)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change1)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank1)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist2)+ """ - <a href=""" +link2+ """>""" +str(song2)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year2)+ """. """ +str(streams2)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change2)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank2)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist3)+ """ - <a href=""" +link3+ """>""" +str(song3)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year3)+ """. """ +str(streams3)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change3)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank3)+ """<br>
        

      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
  """
     
   
  spotifydailyspike(MailInput, MailSubject, MailAdress)

  
elif value == "4":
  artist1 = df.iloc[0,4]
  song1 = df.iloc[0,2]
  change1 = df.iloc[0,1]
  link1 = df.iloc[0,3]
  streams1 = df.iloc[0,6]
  year1 = df.iloc[0,5]
  rank1 = df.iloc[0,0]

  artist2 = df.iloc[1,4]
  song2 = df.iloc[1,2]
  change2 = df.iloc[1,1]
  link2 = df.iloc[1,3]
  streams2 = df.iloc[1,6]
  year2 = df.iloc[1,5]
  rank2 = df.iloc[1,0]
 
  artist3 = df.iloc[2,4]
  song3 = df.iloc[2,2]
  change3 = df.iloc[2,1]
  link3 = df.iloc[2,3]
  streams3 = df.iloc[2,6]
  year3 = df.iloc[2,5]
  rank3 = df.iloc[2,0]

  artist4 = df.iloc[3,4]
  song4 = df.iloc[3,2]
  change4 = df.iloc[3,1]
  link4 = df.iloc[3,3]
  streams4 = df.iloc[3,6]
  year4 = df.iloc[3,5]
  rank4 = df.iloc[3,0]

  def spotifydailyspike(text, subject, recipient):
    import win32com.client as win32   
    import os

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    mail.Display(True)



  MailSubject = "Spotify Daily Spike"
  MailAdress =""
  MailInput =  """\
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <h1 style="font-family:calibri;font-size:30px">TODAY'S SPIKEY SONGS</h1>
    <i><h4 style="font-family:calibri-light;font-size:12px;color:red">THIS IS AN AUTOMATED EMAIL</h4></i>
        <p style="font-family:calibri light">
     """ +str(artist1)+ """ - <a href=""" +link1+ """>""" +str(song1)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year1)+ """. """ +str(streams1)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change1)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank1)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist2)+ """ - <a href=""" +link2+ """>""" +str(song2)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year2)+ """. """ +str(streams2)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change2)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank2)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist3)+ """ - <a href=""" +link3+ """>""" +str(song3)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year3)+ """. """ +str(streams3)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change3)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank3)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist4)+ """ - <a href=""" +link4+ """>""" +str(song4)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year4)+ """. """ +str(streams4)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change4)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank4)+ """<br>        

      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
  """
     
   
  spotifydailyspike(MailInput, MailSubject, MailAdress)



elif value == "5":
  artist1 = df.iloc[0,4]
  song1 = df.iloc[0,2]
  change1 = df.iloc[0,1]
  link1 = df.iloc[0,3]
  streams1 = df.iloc[0,6]
  year1 = df.iloc[0,5]
  rank1 = df.iloc[0,0]

  artist2 = df.iloc[1,4]
  song2 = df.iloc[1,2]
  change2 = df.iloc[1,1]
  link2 = df.iloc[1,3]
  streams2 = df.iloc[1,6]
  year2 = df.iloc[1,5]
  rank2 = df.iloc[1,0]
 
  artist3 = df.iloc[2,4]
  song3 = df.iloc[2,2]
  change3 = df.iloc[2,1]
  link3 = df.iloc[2,3]
  streams3 = df.iloc[2,6]
  year3 = df.iloc[2,5]
  rank3 = df.iloc[2,0]

  artist4 = df.iloc[3,4]
  song4 = df.iloc[3,2]
  change4 = df.iloc[3,1]
  link4 = df.iloc[3,3]
  streams4 = df.iloc[3,6]
  year4 = df.iloc[3,5]
  rank4 = df.iloc[3,0]

  artist5 = df.iloc[4,4]
  song5 = df.iloc[4,2]
  change5 = df.iloc[4,1]
  link5 = df.iloc[4,3]
  streams5 = df.iloc[4,6]
  year5 = df.iloc[4,5]
  rank5 = df.iloc[4,0]

  def spotifydailyspike(text, subject, recipient):
    import win32com.client as win32   
    import os

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    mail.Display(True)



  MailSubject = "Spotify Daily Spike"
  MailAdress =""
  MailInput =  """\
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <h1 style="font-family:calibri;font-size:30px">TODAY'S SPIKEY SONGS</h1>
    <i><h4 style="font-family:calibri-light;font-size:12px;color:red">THIS IS AN AUTOMATED EMAIL</h4></i>
        <p style="font-family:calibri light">
     """ +str(artist1)+ """ - <a href=""" +link1+ """>""" +str(song1)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year1)+ """. """ +str(streams1)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change1)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank1)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist2)+ """ - <a href=""" +link2+ """>""" +str(song2)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year2)+ """. """ +str(streams2)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change2)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank2)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist3)+ """ - <a href=""" +link3+ """>""" +str(song3)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year3)+ """. """ +str(streams3)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change3)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank3)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist4)+ """ - <a href=""" +link4+ """>""" +str(song4)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year4)+ """. """ +str(streams4)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change4)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank4)+ """<br>        
     """ +str(artist5)+ """ - <a href=""" +link5+ """>""" +str(song5)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year5)+ """. """ +str(streams5)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change5)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank5)+ """<br>

      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
  """
     
   
  spotifydailyspike(MailInput, MailSubject, MailAdress)


elif value == "6":
  artist1 = df.iloc[0,4]
  song1 = df.iloc[0,2]
  change1 = df.iloc[0,1]
  link1 = df.iloc[0,3]
  streams1 = df.iloc[0,6]
  year1 = df.iloc[0,5]
  rank1 = df.iloc[0,0]

  artist2 = df.iloc[1,4]
  song2 = df.iloc[1,2]
  change2 = df.iloc[1,1]
  link2 = df.iloc[1,3]
  streams2 = df.iloc[1,6]
  year2 = df.iloc[1,5]
  rank2 = df.iloc[1,0]
 
  artist3 = df.iloc[2,4]
  song3 = df.iloc[2,2]
  change3 = df.iloc[2,1]
  link3 = df.iloc[2,3]
  streams3 = df.iloc[2,6]
  year3 = df.iloc[2,5]
  rank3 = df.iloc[2,0]

  artist4 = df.iloc[3,4]
  song4 = df.iloc[3,2]
  change4 = df.iloc[3,1]
  link4 = df.iloc[3,3]
  streams4 = df.iloc[3,6]
  year4 = df.iloc[3,5]
  rank4 = df.iloc[3,0]

  artist5 = df.iloc[4,4]
  song5 = df.iloc[4,2]
  change5 = df.iloc[4,1]
  link5 = df.iloc[4,3]
  streams5 = df.iloc[4,6]
  year5 = df.iloc[4,5]
  rank5 = df.iloc[4,0]

  artist6 = df.iloc[5,4]
  song6 = df.iloc[5,2]
  change6 = df.iloc[5,1]
  link6 = df.iloc[5,3]
  streams6 = df.iloc[5,6]
  year6 = df.iloc[5,5]
  rank6 = df.iloc[5,0]

  def spotifydailyspike(text, subject, recipient):
    import win32com.client as win32   
    import os

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    mail.Display(True)



  MailSubject = "Spotify Daily Spike"
  MailAdress =""
  MailInput =  """\
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <h1 style="font-family:calibri;font-size:30px">TODAY'S SPIKEY SONGS</h1>
    <i><h4 style="font-family:calibri-light;font-size:12px;color:red">THIS IS AN AUTOMATED EMAIL</h4></i>
        <p style="font-family:calibri light">
     """ +str(artist1)+ """ - <a href=""" +link1+ """>""" +str(song1)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year1)+ """. """ +str(streams1)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change1)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank1)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist2)+ """ - <a href=""" +link2+ """>""" +str(song2)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year2)+ """. """ +str(streams2)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change2)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank2)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist3)+ """ - <a href=""" +link3+ """>""" +str(song3)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year3)+ """. """ +str(streams3)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change3)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank3)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist4)+ """ - <a href=""" +link4+ """>""" +str(song4)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year4)+ """. """ +str(streams4)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change4)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank4)+ """<br>        
     """ +str(artist5)+ """ - <a href=""" +link5+ """>""" +str(song5)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year5)+ """. """ +str(streams5)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change5)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank5)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist6)+ """ - <a href=""" +link6+ """>""" +str(song6)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year6)+ """. """ +str(streams6)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change6)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank6)+ """<br>
      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
  """
     
   
  spotifydailyspike(MailInput, MailSubject, MailAdress)




elif value == "7":
  artist1 = df.iloc[0,4]
  song1 = df.iloc[0,2]
  change1 = df.iloc[0,1]
  link1 = df.iloc[0,3]
  streams1 = df.iloc[0,6]
  year1 = df.iloc[0,5]
  rank1 = df.iloc[0,0]

  artist2 = df.iloc[1,4]
  song2 = df.iloc[1,2]
  change2 = df.iloc[1,1]
  link2 = df.iloc[1,3]
  streams2 = df.iloc[1,6]
  year2 = df.iloc[1,5]
  rank2 = df.iloc[1,0]
 
  artist3 = df.iloc[2,4]
  song3 = df.iloc[2,2]
  change3 = df.iloc[2,1]
  link3 = df.iloc[2,3]
  streams3 = df.iloc[2,6]
  year3 = df.iloc[2,5]
  rank3 = df.iloc[2,0]

  artist4 = df.iloc[3,4]
  song4 = df.iloc[3,2]
  change4 = df.iloc[3,1]
  link4 = df.iloc[3,3]
  streams4 = df.iloc[3,6]
  year4 = df.iloc[3,5]
  rank4 = df.iloc[3,0]

  artist5 = df.iloc[4,4]
  song5 = df.iloc[4,2]
  change5 = df.iloc[4,1]
  link5 = df.iloc[4,3]
  streams5 = df.iloc[4,6]
  year5 = df.iloc[4,5]
  rank5 = df.iloc[4,0]

  artist6 = df.iloc[5,4]
  song6 = df.iloc[5,2]
  change6 = df.iloc[5,1]
  link6 = df.iloc[5,3]
  streams6 = df.iloc[5,6]
  year6 = df.iloc[5,5]
  rank6 = df.iloc[5,0]

  artist7 = df.iloc[6,4]
  song7 = df.iloc[6,2]
  change7 = df.iloc[6,1]
  link7 = df.iloc[6,3]
  streams7 = df.iloc[6,6]
  year7 = df.iloc[6,5]
  rank7 = df.iloc[6,0]

  def spotifydailyspike(text, subject, recipient):
    import win32com.client as win32   
    import os

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    mail.Display(True)



  MailSubject = "Spotify Daily Spike"
  MailAdress =""
  MailInput =  """\
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <h1 style="font-family:calibri;font-size:30px">TODAY'S SPIKEY SONGS</h1>
    <i><h4 style="font-family:calibri-light;font-size:12px;color:red">THIS IS AN AUTOMATED EMAIL</h4></i>
        <p style="font-family:calibri light">
     """ +str(artist1)+ """ - <a href=""" +link1+ """>""" +str(song1)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year1)+ """. """ +str(streams1)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change1)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank1)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist2)+ """ - <a href=""" +link2+ """>""" +str(song2)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year2)+ """. """ +str(streams2)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change2)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank2)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist3)+ """ - <a href=""" +link3+ """>""" +str(song3)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year3)+ """. """ +str(streams3)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change3)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank3)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist4)+ """ - <a href=""" +link4+ """>""" +str(song4)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year4)+ """. """ +str(streams4)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change4)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank4)+ """<br>        
     """ +str(artist5)+ """ - <a href=""" +link5+ """>""" +str(song5)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year5)+ """. """ +str(streams5)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change5)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank5)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist6)+ """ - <a href=""" +link6+ """>""" +str(song6)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year6)+ """. """ +str(streams6)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change6)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank6)+ """<br>
     """ +str(artist7)+ """ - <a href=""" +link7+ """>""" +str(song7)+ """</a>&emsp;| First released in """ +str(year7)+ """. """ +str(streams7)+ """ streams in the past 24 hours, up """ +str(change7)+ """ places to #""" +str(rank7)+ """<br>

      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
  """
     
   
  spotifydailyspike(MailInput, MailSubject, MailAdress)



print("FINISHED")
```

````
Rank,Change,Track,Internal Link,External Link,Artist,Album,Label,Release Date,Streams,Peak Position,Peak Date,7-Day Velocity,Total Days on Chart,ISRC
1,0,As It Was,/track?id=79012900,https://open.spotify.com/track/4LRPiXqCikLlN15c3yImP7,Harry Styles,As It Was,Columbia,"Mar 31, 2022",67358,1,"Apr 01, 2022",4.14,7,USSM12200612
2,0,Heat Waves,/track?id=29681793,https://open.spotify.com/track/02MWAaffLxlfxAUY7c5dvx,Glass Animals,Dreamland (+ Bonus Levels),Polydor Records,"Aug 06, 2020",25974,1,"Mar 20, 2022",-0.14,467,GBUM72000433
3,0,Cold Heart - PNAU Remix,/track?id=56778798,https://open.spotify.com/track/7rglLriMNBPAyuJOMGwi39,"Elton John, Dua Lipa, PNAU",The Lockdown Sessions,EMI,"Oct 22, 2021",24300,1,"Nov 06, 2021",-0.14,167,GBUM72104705
4,0,Starlight,/track?id=75297140,https://open.spotify.com/track/531KGXtBroSrOX9LVmiIgc,Dave,Starlight,Dave / Neighbourhood Recordings,"Mar 03, 2022",22439,4,"Mar 28, 2022",0.14,32,GBUM72201160
5,0,Down Under (feat. Colin Hay),/track?id=66927806,https://open.spotify.com/track/3Oww84xrmgjyr5J1ilOmAf,"Luude, Colin Hay",Down Under (feat. Colin Hay),Sweat It Out!,"Nov 19, 2021",22245,1,"Feb 05, 2022",-0.29,61,AUDCB1701966
6,0,Friday Night,/track?id=53117715,https://open.spotify.com/track/1Ynv5ahQNdRRgDGcMVa3Y6,King George,Friday Night,ACE VISIONZ PRODUCTIONS,"Nov 12, 2020",21538,4,"Mar 02, 2022",-0.29,106,QZNWS2005868
7,0,STAY (with Justin Bieber),/track?id=52404165,https://open.spotify.com/track/5PjdY0CKGZdEuoNab3yDmX,"The Kid LAROI, Justin Bieber",F*CK LOVE 3: OVER YOU,Columbia,"Jul 23, 2021",19721,1,"Jul 23, 2021",0.00,258,USSM12103949
8,0,INDUSTRY BABY (feat. Jack Harlow),/track?id=54095966,https://open.spotify.com/track/5Z9KJZvQzH6PFmb8SNkxuk,"Lil Nas X, Jack Harlow",MONTERO,Columbia,"Sep 17, 2021",19232,1,"Sep 17, 2021",0.43,202,USSM12104539
9,1,Shivers,/track?id=59477833,https://open.spotify.com/track/50nfwKoDiSYg8zOCREWAm5,Ed Sheeran,=,Atlantic Records UK,"Oct 29, 2021",19217,2,"Oct 31, 2021",-0.43,160,GBAHS2100671
10,-1,Enemy (with JID) - from the series Arcane League of Legends,/track?id=65244227,https://open.spotify.com/track/1HhNoOuqm1a5MXYEgAFl8o,"Imagine Dragons, JID, Arcane, League of Legends",Mercury - Act 1,KIDinaKORNER/Interscope Records,"Sep 03, 2021",18792,5,"Mar 19, 2022",-0.29,62,USUM72119916
11,0,In the Air,/track?id=27448698,https://open.spotify.com/track/5v7h5vQgCJKZT5vB3I9s3o,L.A.B.,L.A.B III,Loop Recordings Aot(ear)oa,"Dec 06, 2019",18544,1,"Feb 28, 2020",-0.14,631,NZLP01900490
12,0,Bad Habits,/track?id=50621806,https://open.spotify.com/track/3rmo8F54jFF8OgYsqTxm5d,Ed Sheeran,=,Atlantic Records UK,"Oct 29, 2021",17994,4,"Oct 29, 2021",-0.43,160,GBAHS2100318
13,1,Ghost,/track?id=33649792,https://open.spotify.com/track/6I3mqTwhRpn34SLVafSH7G,Justin Bieber,Justice,RBMG/Def Jam,"Mar 19, 2021",17509,10,"Mar 14, 2022",-0.14,192,USUM72102635
14,-1,MIDDLE OF THE NIGHT,/track?id=28140531,https://open.spotify.com/track/58HvfVOeJY7lUuCqF0m3ly,Elley Duhé,MIDDLE OF THE NIGHT,Not Fit For Society/RCA Records,"Jan 10, 2020",17089,13,"Apr 04, 2022",0.29,54,USRC11903813
15,0,Easy On Me,/track?id=63926722,https://open.spotify.com/track/46IZ0fSY2mpAiktS3KOqds,Adele,30,Columbia,"Nov 19, 2021",17070,1,"Nov 19, 2021",-0.29,139,USSM12105970
16,2,Mr Reggae,/track?id=67463129,https://open.spotify.com/track/6J6slpqRf9jYqGUVKVEOOt,L.A.B.,L.A.B V,Loop Recordings Aot(ear)oa,"Dec 17, 2021",16321,1,"Dec 17, 2021",-0.29,111,NZLP02200722
17,2,Where Are You Now,/track?id=55335292,https://open.spotify.com/track/3uUuGVFu1V7jTQL60S1r8z,"Lost Frequencies, Calum Scott",Where Are You Now,Epic Amsterdam,"Jul 30, 2021",16211,14,"Mar 25, 2022",0.00,122,BEHP42100067
18,-2,Woman,/track?id=50643187,https://open.spotify.com/track/6Uj1ctrBOjOas8xZXGqKk4,Doja Cat,Planet Her,Kemosabe Records/RCA Records,"Jun 25, 2021",16197,6,"Sep 11, 2021",0.14,267,USRC12101532
19,1,Freaky Deaky,/track?id=74525665,https://open.spotify.com/track/3vySEUpD0tc801F2WZDLYw,"Tyga, Doja Cat",Freaky Deaky,Kemosabe / RCA Records / Last Kings Music / EMPIRE,"Feb 25, 2022",16098,15,"Mar 17, 2022",-0.14,40,USUYG1414608
20,-3,Tom's Diner,/track?id=24229707,https://open.spotify.com/track/0oA9wBGDY4uyILLg4GymWP,"AnnenMayKantereit, Giant Rooks",Tom's Diner,Vertigo Berlin,"Jun 28, 2019",15957,13,"Mar 28, 2022",-0.71,25,DEUM71903009
21,3,Dreams - 2004 Remaster,/track?id=16026997,https://open.spotify.com/track/0ofHAoxe9vBkTCp2UQIavz,Fleetwood Mac,Rumours (Super Deluxe),Rhino/Warner Records,"Feb 04, 1977",15629,4,"Oct 24, 2020",0.00,"1,698",USWB11301111
22,1,Bam Bam (feat. Ed Sheeran),/track?id=75283401,https://open.spotify.com/track/0QBzMgT7NIeoCYy3sJCof1,"Camila Cabello, Ed Sheeran",Bam Bam (feat. Ed Sheeran),Epic,"Mar 04, 2022",15321,20,"Apr 04, 2022",0.57,34,USSM12200047
23,-2,No Role Modelz,/track?id=15619977,https://open.spotify.com/track/68Dni7IE4VyPkTOH9mRWHr,J. Cole,2014 Forest Hills Drive,Roc Nation Records LLC,"Dec 09, 2014",15130,20,"Mar 30, 2022",-0.14,93,USQX91402598
24,1,good 4 u,/track?id=41340637,https://open.spotify.com/track/4ZtFanR9U6ndgddUvNcjcG,Olivia Rodrigo,SOUR,Olivia Rodrigo PS,"May 21, 2021",14698,1,"May 21, 2021",1.43,321,USUG12101245
25,-3,THATS WHAT I WANT,/track?id=60290154,https://open.spotify.com/track/0e8nrvls4Qqv5Rfa2UhqmO,Lil Nas X,MONTERO,Columbia,"Sep 17, 2021",14649,3,"Sep 19, 2021",-0.29,203,USSM12105732
26,3,abcdefu,/track?id=56814906,https://open.spotify.com/track/4fouWK6XVHhzl78KzQ1UjL,GAYLE,abcdefu,Atlantic/Arthouse Records,"Aug 13, 2021",14431,3,"Dec 06, 2021",-0.86,144,USAT22103652
27,4,Controller,/track?id=17738774,https://open.spotify.com/track/2DkxWMmdvS3f5hbz4UGQLO,L.A.B.,L.A.B,Loop Recordings Aot(ear)oa,"Nov 24, 2017",14340,3,"Dec 26, 2020",0.71,875,NZLP01700337
28,0,Lost,/track?id=15923620,https://open.spotify.com/track/3GZD6HmiNUhxXYf8Gch723,Frank Ocean,channel ORANGE,Red Zone Entertainment / IDJ,"Jul 10, 2012",14142,19,"Mar 03, 2022",-0.57,35,USUM71207186
29,1,Kiss Me More (feat. SZA),/track?id=34026721,https://open.spotify.com/track/3DarAbFujv6eYNliUTyqtz,"Doja Cat, SZA",Planet Her,Kemosabe Records/RCA Records,"Jun 25, 2021",13909,2,"Jun 25, 2021",0.57,286,USRC12100543
30,-4,Boyfriend,/track?id=73438272,https://open.spotify.com/track/59CfNbkERJ3NoTXDvoURjj,Dove Cameron,Boyfriend,Disruptor Records/Columbia,"Feb 11, 2022",13890,12,"Mar 09, 2022",-0.43,55,USQX92200693
31,-4,Numb Little Bug,/track?id=72731976,https://open.spotify.com/track/3o9kpgkIcffx0iSwxhuNI2,Em Beihold,Numb Little Bug,"Republic Records/Moon Projects, LLC.","Jan 28, 2022",13857,24,"Mar 10, 2022",-0.86,69,USUM72200626
32,1,Here For You,/track?id=73441931,https://open.spotify.com/track/1QgebV92VO4Z7VxbQ1tSKo,"Wilkinson, Becky Hill",Cognition,BMG Rights Management (UK) Limited,"Feb 11, 2022",13679,5,"Feb 11, 2022",-0.14,56,GB5KW2104629
33,3,Nail Tech,/track?id=73641661,https://open.spotify.com/track/62Yo3FDddWY8ydu6PW2wyz,Jack Harlow,Nail Tech,Generation Now/Atlantic,"Feb 18, 2022",13581,19,"Feb 23, 2022",2.00,48,USAT22200223
34,-2,Fingers Crossed,/track?id=69188915,https://open.spotify.com/track/3yMC1KsTwh0ceXdIe4QQAQ,Lauren Spencer-Smith,Fingers Crossed,"Three Name Productions, Inc./ Island Records & Republic Records","Jan 05, 2022",13206,13,"Feb 09, 2022",-0.86,57,TCAFY2118876
35,2,Under the Sun,/track?id=68461762,https://open.spotify.com/track/1GQ7M3b1B4Dt9lMjoBOGcl,L.A.B.,L.A.B V,Loop Recordings Aot(ear)oa,"Dec 17, 2021",12858,7,"Dec 17, 2021",0.14,112,NZLP02200723
36,-2,Wait a Minute!,/track?id=13904490,https://open.spotify.com/track/0y60itmpH0aPKsFiGxmtnh,WILLOW,ARDIPITHECUS,Roc Nation W Smith P&D,"Jan 11, 2015",12718,34,"Apr 05, 2022",4.14,150,QMJMT1500801
37,2,Keep On Rollin,/track?id=72888783,https://open.spotify.com/track/3fRQ3919obMjRReHeoE4gH,King George,Keep On Rollin,ACE VISIONZ PRODUCTIONS,"Feb 14, 2022",12647,30,"Mar 11, 2022",0.00,45,QZFZ32236574
38,0,edamame (feat. Rich Brian),/track?id=54097040,https://open.spotify.com/track/5rW7qTn83sCKtqBoneJs63,"bbno$, Rich Brian",eat ya veggies,bbno$,"Oct 08, 2021",12509,25,"Mar 05, 2022",0.00,180,QMUY42100151
39,1,Light Switch,/track?id=69560913,https://open.spotify.com/track/3AVXwaOGCEL8cmBecfcsFJ,Charlie Puth,Light Switch (Instrumental),Atlantic Records,"Jan 19, 2022",12501,22,"Feb 07, 2022",0.29,62,USAT22107359
40,5,Why Oh Why,/track?id=32150616,https://open.spotify.com/track/3TaGtHDHWQ7TfPpX0eJrtB,L.A.B.,L.A.B IV,Loop Recordings Aot(ear)oa,"Dec 18, 2020",12144,1,"Dec 18, 2020",1.86,475,NZLP02000621
41,3,Cool it down,/track?id=68104261,https://open.spotify.com/track/3fT0AXVjnu3a3hUpyl8M6e,COTERIE,Cool it down,Sony Music Entertainment,"Dec 03, 2021",12129,40,"Apr 01, 2022",0.71,38,AUMEV2176726
42,-1,We Don't Talk About Bruno,/track?id=66986384,https://open.spotify.com/track/52xJxFP6TqMuO4Yt0eOkMz,"Carolina Gaitán - La Gaita, Mauro Castillo, Adassa, Rhenzy Feliz, Diane Guerrero, Stephanie Beatriz, Encanto - Cast",Encanto (Original Motion Picture Soundtrack),Walt Disney Records,"Nov 19, 2021",12106,3,"Feb 05, 2022",-1.86,101,USWD12112915
43,-8,When You're Gone,/track?id=78915804,https://open.spotify.com/track/0U1W2LZVUX7qTm7dDpqxh6,Shawn Mendes,When You're Gone,Shawn Mendes LP4-5 PS/ Island,"Mar 31, 2022",12019,35,"Apr 06, 2022",8.14,7,USUM72204098
44,-2,she's all i wanna be,/track?id=73278693,https://open.spotify.com/track/0IuVhCflrQPMGRrOyoY5RW,Tate McRae,she's all i wanna be,RCA Records Label,"Feb 04, 2022",11829,25,"Feb 28, 2022",-0.57,62,USRC12103120
45,3,Big Energy,/track?id=61602980,https://open.spotify.com/track/4pi1G1x8tl9VfdD9bL3maT,Latto,777,Streamcut/RCA Records,"Mar 25, 2022",11511,36,"Mar 25, 2022",-0.86,13,USRC12102454
46,-3,Just A Cloud Away,/track?id=78134581,https://open.spotify.com/track/0DGTcMqvVR7fmBXgiG6jz4,Pharrell Williams,Just A Cloud Away,Columbia,"Jan 01, 2013",11216,17,"Mar 25, 2022",-1.57,13,USQX92201647
47,0,Everlong,/track?id=15717288,https://open.spotify.com/track/5UWwZ5lm5PKu6eKsHAGxOk,Foo Fighters,The Colour And The Shape,RCA Records Label,"May 20, 1997",10753,30,"Mar 27, 2022",-0.71,25,USRW29600011
48,1,Do It To It,/track?id=57467910,https://open.spotify.com/track/20on25jryn53hWghthWWW3,"ACRAZE, Cherish",Do It To It,"Thrive Music, LLC","Aug 20, 2021",10747,11,"Dec 31, 2021",-0.43,157,QZFPL2100100
49,1,KELZ GARAGE (feat. Lomez Brown),/track?id=68066178,https://open.spotify.com/track/61Mo1EqfJ42Ww3BhO3nvCT,"SWIDT, Lomez Brown",312 DAY,Universal Music New Zealand & Australia (Distribution),"Dec 02, 2021",10705,49,"Apr 01, 2022",0.14,53,NZWD02100003
50,2,Levitating (feat. DaBaby),/track?id=31526926,https://open.spotify.com/track/5nujrmhLynf4yMoMtj8AQF,"Dua Lipa, DaBaby",Future Nostalgia,Warner Records,"Mar 27, 2020",10638,5,"Jan 02, 2021",-0.29,517,GBAHT2000942
51,0,Takeover,/track?id=26810154,https://open.spotify.com/track/7ArG7cEuyvTNXDwW7stm85,"Lee Mvtthews, NÜ",Bones,Lee Mvtthews,"Nov 01, 2019",10484,23,"Feb 25, 2022",-1.14,345,NZAM01902823
52,-6,In My Head,/track?id=78964339,https://open.spotify.com/track/1HvTxgCj0mTzQlEo0zLvFb,Lil Tjay,In My Head,Columbia,"Apr 01, 2022",10297,34,"Apr 03, 2022",,6,USSM12202421
53,4,Still D.R.E.,/track?id=15417010,https://open.spotify.com/track/503OTo2dSqe7qk76rgsbep,"Dr. Dre, Snoop Dogg",2001,Aftermath,"Nov 16, 1999",10142,15,"Feb 16, 2022",0.29,67,USIR19905031
54,1,Mr. Brightside,/track?id=15419058,https://open.spotify.com/track/003vvx7Niy0yvhvHt4a68B,The Killers,Hot Fuss,Island Records,"Jan 01, 2004",10008,26,"Dec 31, 2021",0.71,605,USIR20400274
55,4,Following the Sun,/track?id=31522299,https://open.spotify.com/track/5A5bLKdL5I3k3FTEQlAUw7,"SUPER-Hi, Neeka",Following the Sun,BLENDED,"Aug 20, 2021",9999,55,"Apr 03, 2022",1.00,30,SE5BU2081473
56,-2,traitor,/track?id=43417294,https://open.spotify.com/track/5CZ40GBx1sQ9agT82CLQCT,Olivia Rodrigo,SOUR,Olivia Rodrigo PS,"May 21, 2021",9871,3,"Jun 15, 2021",2.57,319,USUG12101243
57,4,Without Me,/track?id=15414251,https://open.spotify.com/track/7lQ8MOhq6IN2w8EYcFNSUk,Eminem,The Eminem Show,Aftermath,"May 26, 2002",9843,51,"Feb 22, 2022",0.43,230,USIR10211038
58,-2,drivers license,/track?id=32507149,https://open.spotify.com/track/5wANPM4fQCJwkGd4rN57mH,Olivia Rodrigo,SOUR,Olivia Rodrigo PS,"May 21, 2021",9828,4,"May 23, 2021",4.43,319,USUG12004749
59,4,The Real Slim Shady,/track?id=15413181,https://open.spotify.com/track/3yfqSUWxFvZELEM4PmlwIR,Eminem,The Marshall Mathers LP,Interscope,"May 23, 2000",9750,55,"Feb 24, 2022",-0.29,365,USIR10000448
60,-7,Need to Know,/track?id=48699803,https://open.spotify.com/track/3Vi5XqYrmQgOYBajMWSvCi,Doja Cat,Planet Her,Kemosabe Records/RCA Records,"Jun 25, 2021",9730,4,"Aug 18, 2021",-0.29,286,USRC12101120
61,-3,Infinity,/track?id=15093243,https://open.spotify.com/track/1SOClUWhOi8vHZYMz3GluK,Jaymes Young,Feel Something,Atlantic Records,"Jun 23, 2017",9723,40,"Mar 23, 2022",-2.43,120,USAT21700859
62,0,Go - goddard. Remix,/track?id=75320926,https://open.spotify.com/track/7kjANxR8XN4hCzLaSc2roy,"Cat Burns, goddard.",Go (goddard. Remix),Since 93,"Mar 04, 2022",9493,62,"Apr 06, 2022",,4,GBARL2200333
63,-3,Better Days (NEIKED x Mae Muller x Polo G),/track?id=61491313,https://open.spotify.com/track/6f5ExP43esnvdKPddwKXJH,"NEIKED, Mae Muller, Polo G",Better Days (NEIKED x Mae Muller x Polo G),Capitol,"Sep 24, 2021",9445,9,"Nov 02, 2021",-0.29,171,GBUM72106057
64,9,35,/track?id=58801375,https://open.spotify.com/track/6vFlODh4lr7VOho2MFxXvL,"Rob Ruha, Ka Hao",35,InDigiNation,"Sep 03, 2021",9323,11,"Nov 18, 2021",0.29,212,NZAM02102791
65,1,Oh My God,/track?id=66902232,https://open.spotify.com/track/3Kkjo3cT83cw09VJyrLNwX,Adele,30,Columbia,"Nov 19, 2021",9287,2,"Nov 22, 2021",-0.14,140,USSM12105973
66,1,Watermelon Sugar,/track?id=27222889,https://open.spotify.com/track/6UelLqGlWMcVH1E5c4H7lY,Harry Styles,Fine Line,Columbia,"Dec 13, 2019",9233,4,"Dec 13, 2019",3.71,844,USSM11912587
67,-3,Happier Than Ever,/track?id=55332293,https://open.spotify.com/track/4RVwu0g32PAqgUiJoXsdF8,Billie Eilish,Happier Than Ever,Darkroom/Interscope Records,"Jul 30, 2021",9139,3,"Aug 04, 2021",4.43,249,USUM72105936
68,8,Blinding Lights,/track?id=27552418,https://open.spotify.com/track/0VjIjW4GlUZAMYd2vXMi3b,The Weeknd,After Hours,Republic Records,"Mar 20, 2020",9055,1,"Mar 21, 2020",0.14,745,USUG11904206
69,0,TO THE MOON,/track?id=65782871,https://open.spotify.com/track/5vUnjhBzRJJIAOJPde6zDx,"Jnr Choi, Sam Tompkins",TO THE MOON,Jnr Choi/Epic,"Nov 06, 2021",9009,34,"Feb 26, 2022",-2.43,71,QZNWW2131527
70,5,Hit 'Em Up - Single Version,/track?id=15893156,https://open.spotify.com/track/0Z2J91b2iTGLVTZC4fKgxf,"2Pac, Outlawz",Greatest Hits,2Pac Greatest Hits,"Jan 01, 1998",8859,64,"Mar 17, 2022",-0.29,71,USUG10801475
71,-3,Leave The Door Open,/track?id=33210584,https://open.spotify.com/track/02VBYrHfVwfEWXk5DXyf0T,"Bruno Mars, Anderson .Paak, Silk Sonic",An Evening With Silk Sonic,Aftermath Entertainment/Atlantic,"Nov 11, 2021",8825,57,"Apr 04, 2022",13.29,22,USAT22100906
72,8,The Motto,/track?id=65547840,https://open.spotify.com/track/18asYwWugKjjsihZ0YvRxO,"Tiësto, Ava Max",The Motto,Atlantic Records,"Nov 04, 2021",8816,70,"Mar 30, 2022",-0.29,98,CYA112001070
73,-8,Sweater Weather,/track?id=15790443,https://open.spotify.com/track/2QjOHCTQ1Jl3zawyYOpxh6,The Neighbourhood,I Love You.,Columbia,"Apr 19, 2013",8799,65,"Mar 20, 2022",0.71,502,USSM11300080
74,4,Someone To Be Around - Bonus Track,/track?id=64323491,https://open.spotify.com/track/7KkpWFfKfSivkMD6yrKhGD,SIX60,GOLD ALBUM (10th Anniversary Edition),Universal Music New Zealand Limited (Distribution),"Oct 21, 2021",8784,34,"Dec 26, 2021",-1.00,167,NZMI12100018
75,2,Sweetest Pie,/track?id=75856195,https://open.spotify.com/track/7mFj0LlWtEJaEigguaWqYh,"Megan Thee Stallion, Dua Lipa",Sweetest Pie,300 Entertainment,"Mar 11, 2022",8751,18,"Mar 14, 2022",-2.71,27,QMCE32200232
76,7,Save Your Tears (Remix) (with Ariana Grande) - Bonus Track,/track?id=34728848,https://open.spotify.com/track/1oFAF1hdPOickyHgbuRjyX,"The Weeknd, Ariana Grande",After Hours (Deluxe),XO / Republic Records,"Mar 20, 2020",8708,62,"Mar 21, 2022",3.57,16,USUG12101839
77,2,Wet Dreamz,/track?id=15619971,https://open.spotify.com/track/4tqcoej1zPvwePZCzuAjJd,J. Cole,2014 Forest Hills Drive,Roc Nation Records LLC,"Dec 09, 2014",8704,70,"Mar 22, 2022",0.71,74,USQX91402592
78,10,Don’t Forget Your Roots,/track?id=13710802,https://open.spotify.com/track/5mUiad5pDU1wFvIbtKgJKB,SIX60,Six60,Universal Music New Zealand Limited,"Jan 01, 2011",8668,18,"Apr 24, 2021",-1.00,"1,658",NZMI11100001
79,-7,Over,/track?id=61321186,https://open.spotify.com/track/23CKxEwKWsLs6LD5poGOLM,Lucky Daye,Candydrip,Keep Cool/RCA Records,"Mar 10, 2022",8621,46,"Mar 30, 2022",-3.57,20,USRC12102179
80,-9,Dandelions,/track?id=15799454,https://open.spotify.com/track/2eAvDnpXP5W0cVtiI0PUxV,Ruth B.,Safe Haven,Columbia,"May 05, 2017",8553,61,"Mar 20, 2022",-0.57,72,USSM11703468
81,-7,Mount Everest,/track?id=24136343,https://open.spotify.com/track/1ZdhOMWyFR8Iv9eylMGYg2,Labrinth,Imagination & the Misfit Kid,Syco Music,"Nov 22, 2019",8516,31,"Mar 10, 2022",-4.29,58,GBHMU1800032
82,11,Hypnotize - 2014 Remaster,/track?id=15088810,https://open.spotify.com/track/7KwZNVEaqikRSBSpyhXK2j,The Notorious B.I.G.,Life After Death (2014 Remastered Edition),Rhino Atlantic,"Mar 04, 1997",8512,67,"Mar 24, 2022",-0.71,262,USAT21402725
83,-13,Birthday Cake,/track?id=73138675,https://open.spotify.com/track/7dDrR6vMK1JAwZZ5MIWgme,Dylan Conrique,Birthday Cake,KYN Entertainment,"Feb 02, 2022",8497,64,"Apr 03, 2022",-1.43,18,ZZOPM2220577
84,-2,Baby,/track?id=75783908,https://open.spotify.com/track/3pudQCMnsFGwOElTZmuml8,"Aitch, Ashanti",Baby,Capitol,"Mar 10, 2022",8382,82,"Apr 06, 2022",5.43,15,GBUM72201110
85,4,deja vu,/track?id=33837370,https://open.spotify.com/track/6HU7h9RYOaPRFeh0R3UeAr,Olivia Rodrigo,SOUR,Olivia Rodrigo PS,"May 21, 2021",8355,2,"May 23, 2021",5.57,302,USUG12101240
86,-5,Meet Me At Our Spot,/track?id=28737183,https://open.spotify.com/track/07MDkzWARZaLEdKxo6yArG,"THE ANXIETY, WILLOW, Tyler Cole",THE ANXIETY,"MSFTSMusic / Roc Nation Records, LLC","Mar 13, 2020",8259,6,"Oct 20, 2021",-0.71,228,QMJMT2002693
87,-3,Stan,/track?id=15413508,https://open.spotify.com/track/3UmaczJpikHgJFyBTAJVoz,"Eminem, Dido",The Marshall Mathers LP,Interscope,"May 23, 2000",8237,80,"Mar 29, 2022",-0.14,64,USIR10001280
88,4,Someone You Loved,/track?id=21918634,https://open.spotify.com/track/7qEHsqek33rTcFNT9PFqLf,Lewis Capaldi,Divinely Uninspired To A Hellish Extent,Vertigo Berlin,"May 17, 2019",8206,3,"Jun 04, 2019",-0.57,"1,054",DEUM71807062
89,-3,Knife Talk (with 21 Savage ft. Project Pat),/track?id=58853129,https://open.spotify.com/track/2BcMwX1MPV6ZHP4tUT9uq6,"Drake, 21 Savage, Project Pat",Certified Lover Boy,OVO,"Sep 03, 2021",8185,7,"Sep 05, 2021",-0.14,213,USUG12104409
90,5,Catching Feelings (feat. SIX60),/track?id=25075281,https://open.spotify.com/track/0gCNs3jCCDhObAK0MRghtv,"Drax Project, SIX60",Drax Project,300 Entertainment,"Sep 27, 2019",8108,3,"Oct 01, 2019",0.00,919,QMCE31902432
91,0,Sunflower - Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse,/track?id=21815071,https://open.spotify.com/track/0RiRZpuVRbi7oqRdSMwhQY,"Post Malone, Swae Lee",Hollywood's Bleeding,Republic Records,"Sep 06, 2019",8102,18,"Dec 05, 2019",-2.71,930,USUM71814888
92,-2,Hrs & Hrs,/track?id=66959718,https://open.spotify.com/track/3M5azWqeZbfoVkGXygatlb,Muni Long,Public Displays Of Affection,"Supergiant Records, LLC / Def Jam Recordings","Nov 19, 2021",8015,40,"Mar 22, 2022",-4.14,16,QZAKB2136210
93,15,Go Your Own Way - 2004 Remaster,/track?id=16016837,https://open.spotify.com/track/07GvNcU1WdyZJq3XxP0kZa,Fleetwood Mac,Rumours,Rhino/Warner Records,"Feb 04, 1977",8003,33,"Dec 31, 2021",-1.14,"1,435",USWB10400050
94,-7,Softcore,/track?id=18714857,https://open.spotify.com/track/2K7xn816oNHJZ0aVqdQsha,The Neighbourhood,Hard To Imagine The Neighbourhood Ever Changing,Columbia,"Nov 02, 2018",7994,61,"Feb 13, 2022",3.86,88,USSM11800523
95,-10,Revenge,/track?id=15972113,https://open.spotify.com/track/5TXDeTFVRVY7Cvt0Dw4vWW,XXXTENTACION,17,Bad Vibes Forever / EMPIRE,"Aug 25, 2017",7899,24,"Jun 19, 2018",-2.14,149,USUYG1156895
96,2,Yes I Do,/track?id=32317413,https://open.spotify.com/track/6oTbxrszNWRsLdwFkGeHy6,L.A.B.,L.A.B IV,Loop Recordings Aot(ear)oa,"Dec 18, 2020",7889,7,"Dec 18, 2020",2.14,476,NZLP02000623
97,6,Money Trees,/track?id=15924392,https://open.spotify.com/track/2HbKqm4o0w5wEeEFXm2sD4,"Kendrick Lamar, Jay Rock","good kid, m.A.A.d city",Aftermath,"Jan 01, 2012",7808,21,"Aug 28, 2020",2.29,482,USUM71210785
98,11,Ain't Shit,/track?id=50643171,https://open.spotify.com/track/5lAnYvAIkSDNXqfo7DyFUm,Doja Cat,Planet Her,Kemosabe Records/RCA Records,"Jun 25, 2021",7786,6,"Jul 24, 2021",6.86,181,USRC12101540
99,-2,505,/track?id=12630649,https://open.spotify.com/track/58ge6dfP91o9oXMzq3XkIS,Arctic Monkeys,Favourite Worst Nightmare (Standard Version),Domino/Warner Records,"Apr 24, 2007",7776,88,"Mar 20, 2022",2.29,53,GBCEL0700074
100,2,2055,/track?id=34451527,https://open.spotify.com/track/4XvcHTUfIlWfyJTRG0aqlo,Sleepy Hallow,Still Sleep?,Winners Circle/RCA Records,"Jun 02, 2021",7770,9,"Aug 17, 2021",-1.00,265,USRC12100442
101,0,Pepeha,/track?id=58114994,https://open.spotify.com/track/7A1SKLC7QhybSkcIekJFxM,SIX60,Pepeha,Universal Music New Zealand Limited,"Aug 27, 2021",7761,4,"Aug 27, 2021",-2.00,223,NZMI12100002
102,-3,"Lose Yourself - From ""8 Mile"" Soundtrack",/track?id=15414496,https://open.spotify.com/track/1v7L65Lzy0j0vdpRjJewt1,Eminem,Just Lose It,Aftermath,"Jan 01, 2004",7745,59,"Feb 16, 2022",-3.29,77,USIR10211559
103,8,Peaches (feat. Daniel Caesar & Giveon),/track?id=33631904,https://open.spotify.com/track/4iJyoBOLtHqaGxP12qzhQI,"Justin Bieber, Daniel Caesar, Giveon",Justice,RBMG/Def Jam,"Mar 19, 2021",7716,1,"Mar 21, 2021",0.71,383,USUM72102636
104,-8,I Love You So,/track?id=14312336,https://open.spotify.com/track/4SqWKzw0CbA05TGszDgMlc,The Walters,I Love You So,Warner Records,"Nov 28, 2014",7622,58,"Feb 13, 2022",-1.43,140,TCACC1438995
105,-11,Another Love,/track?id=12491171,https://open.spotify.com/track/7jtQIBanIiJOMS6RyCx6jZ,Tom Odell,Long Way Down,ITNO/Columbia,"Jun 17, 2013",7620,71,"Mar 21, 2022",0.57,71,GBARL1300107
106,-2,Wavy,/track?id=32927700,https://open.spotify.com/track/6fZmJKpBSqMRx49KaY4waD,Muroki,Wavy,Universal Music New Zealand Limited (Distribution),"Feb 25, 2021",7619,20,"Aug 17, 2021",-2.14,281,NZOL02100001
107,-7,I AM WOMAN,/track?id=66960651,https://open.spotify.com/track/3nOz1U41SZZ0N3fuUWr9nb,Emmy Meli,I AM WOMAN,Disruptor Records/Arista Records,"Nov 19, 2021",7597,11,"Dec 13, 2021",-1.14,138,USAR12100239
108,-1,Redbone,/track?id=16077707,https://open.spotify.com/track/0wXuerDYiBnERgIpbb3JBR,Childish Gambino,"""Awaken, My Love!""",Glassnote Entertainment Group LLC,"Dec 02, 2016",7561,71,"Mar 16, 2022",-0.29,502,USYAH1600107
109,1,All She Wrote,/track?id=32927711,https://open.spotify.com/track/2yI8xyHgyhCXyw0Vq98twb,SIX60,All She Wrote,Universal Music New Zealand Limited,"Feb 26, 2021",7496,1,"Feb 26, 2021",-1.71,406,USSM12100552
110,2,Hotel California - 2013 Remaster,/track?id=15273529,https://open.spotify.com/track/40riOy7x9W7GXjyGp4pjAv,Eagles,Hotel California (2013 Remaster),Rhino/Elektra,"Dec 08, 1976",7472,45,"Dec 31, 2021",-1.00,"2,009",USEE11300353
111,-5,Sex on Fire,/track?id=15673749,https://open.spotify.com/track/0ntQJM78wzOLVeCUAW7Y45,Kings of Leon,Only By The Night,RCA/Legacy,"Sep 23, 2008",7410,69,"Aug 07, 2021",-1.29,531,USRC10800300
112,23,Africa,/track?id=15821286,https://open.spotify.com/track/2374M0fQpWi3dLnB54qaLX,TOTO,Toto IV,Columbia,"Apr 08, 1982",7383,32,"Dec 31, 2018",8.29,"1,628",USSM19801941
113,1,Smokin Out The Window,/track?id=65690618,https://open.spotify.com/track/3xVZYkcuWalGudeKl861wb,"Bruno Mars, Anderson .Paak, Silk Sonic",An Evening With Silk Sonic,Aftermath Entertainment/Atlantic,"Nov 11, 2021",7340,113,"Apr 07, 2022",10.86,21,USAT22105952
114,4,Don't Stop Believin',/track?id=15811629,https://open.spotify.com/track/4bHsxqR3GMrXTxEPLuK5ue,Journey,Escape,Columbia,"Jan 01, 1981",7302,44,"Dec 31, 2021",-1.29,"1,722",USSM18100116
115,4,Shallow,/track?id=20614204,https://open.spotify.com/track/2VxeLyX666F8uXCJ0dZF8B,"Lady Gaga, Bradley Cooper",A Star Is Born Soundtrack,A Star is Born OST,"Oct 05, 2018",7287,1,"Oct 25, 2018",-2.71,"1,277",USUM71813192
116,-3,Dark Red,/track?id=12861012,https://open.spotify.com/track/37y7iDayfwm3WXn5BiAoRk,Steve Lacy,Dark Red,Three Quarter,"Feb 20, 2017",7264,48,"Aug 25, 2021",1.43,233,GBKPL1778015
117,5,Party In The U.S.A.,/track?id=15393046,https://open.spotify.com/track/3E7dfMvvCLUddWissuqMwr,Miley Cyrus,The Time Of Our Lives (International Version),Hollywood Records,"Jan 01, 2009",7237,54,"Dec 31, 2021",0.00,"1,134",USHR10924519
118,3,Chosen (feat. Ty Dolla $ign),/track?id=32150588,https://open.spotify.com/track/1dIWPXMX4kRHj6Dt2DStUQ,"Blxst, Tyga, Ty Dolla $ign",No Love Lost (Deluxe),Red Bull Records Inc. / Evgle LLC,"Dec 04, 2020",7195,28,"Oct 12, 2021",-0.57,430,USP6L2000552
119,-14,Something In The Way - Remastered,/track?id=15361122,https://open.spotify.com/track/2WL6GQzPuK9Nrpy9XwNEbz,Nirvana,Nevermind (30th Anniversary Super Deluxe),Geffen,"Sep 24, 1991",7164,27,"Mar 20, 2022",-6.29,31,USGF19942512
120,20,In Da Club,/track?id=15414667,https://open.spotify.com/track/7iL6o9tox1zgHpKUfh9vuC,50 Cent,Get Rich Or Die Tryin',Shady Records,"Feb 06, 2003",7128,58,"Feb 18, 2022",2.14,58,USIR10300033
121,3,Big Poppa - 2005 Remaster,/track?id=15117473,https://open.spotify.com/track/2g8HN35AnVGIk7B8yMucww,The Notorious B.I.G.,Ready to Die (The Remaster),Bad Boy Records,"Sep 13, 1994",7120,101,"Feb 22, 2022",0.57,156,USBB40580817
122,-6,Riptide,/track?id=11005892,https://open.spotify.com/track/7yq4Qj7cqayVTp3FF9CWbm,Vance Joy,Dream Your Life Away,F-Stop Records/Atlantic,"Sep 08, 2014",7075,87,"Feb 15, 2017",-2.57,"1,555",AULI01385760
123,0,MONTERO (Call Me By Your Name),/track?id=33735279,https://open.spotify.com/track/1SC5rEoYDGUK4NfG82494W,Lil Nas X,MONTERO,Columbia,"Sep 17, 2021",7071,9,"Sep 17, 2021",1.14,201,USSM12100531
124,-9,Say You Won't Let Go,/track?id=11500844,https://open.spotify.com/track/5uCax9HTNlzGybIStD3vDh,James Arthur,Back from the Edge,Columbia,"Oct 28, 2016",7062,2,"Nov 02, 2016",-2.00,"1,965",DEE861600586
125,2,Work Out,/track?id=15617582,https://open.spotify.com/track/2wAJTrFhCnQyNSD3oUgTZO,J. Cole,Cole World: The Sideline Story,Roc Nation LLC,"Sep 27, 2011",7052,98,"Sep 28, 2021",1.71,378,USQX91100801
126,-9,pushin P (feat. Young Thug),/track?id=69230812,https://open.spotify.com/track/3XOalgusokruzA5ZBA2Qcb,"Gunna, Future, Young Thug",DS4EVER,300 Entertainment,"Jan 13, 2022",7044,14,"Feb 02, 2022",-2.71,71,QMCE32200039
127,9,Smells Like Teen Spirit - Remastered,/track?id=15361111,https://open.spotify.com/track/0gucTLf7trAf37Ua1uAyAu,Nirvana,Nevermind (30th Anniversary Super Deluxe),Geffen,"Sep 24, 1991",6989,115,"Mar 28, 2022",0.00,129,USGF19942501
128,13,Used To This,/track?id=66927833,https://open.spotify.com/track/37nGZSaEXsKzOZLINC3VOp,"Wilkinson, Issey Cross",Cognition,BMG Rights Management (UK) Limited,"Feb 11, 2022",6986,28,"Feb 11, 2022",-2.29,55,GB5KW2104422
129,10,Sundown,/track?id=26957652,https://open.spotify.com/track/4WEAdAPGiyI6LIMlHGfhdZ,SIX60,Six60,Universal Music New Zealand Limited,"Nov 08, 2019",6971,5,"Dec 26, 2020",-1.29,765,USSM11912566
130,4,The Chain - 2004 Remaster,/track?id=16027002,https://open.spotify.com/track/5e9TFTbltYBg2xThimr0rU,Fleetwood Mac,Rumours (Super Deluxe),Rhino/Warner Records,"Feb 04, 1977",6966,49,"Sep 21, 2019",-0.14,"1,065",USWB11301116
131,12,Don't Start Now,/track?id=26822879,https://open.spotify.com/track/3PfIrDoz19wz7qK7tYeu62,Dua Lipa,Future Nostalgia,Warner Records,"Mar 27, 2020",6949,3,"Mar 27, 2020",1.71,738,GBAHT1901121
132,-2,Love on the Run (feat. Jackson Owens),/track?id=47001694,https://open.spotify.com/track/6YHsPMvvmor0vFrMxI4UZi,"Sons Of Zion, Jackson Owens",Love on the Run (feat. Jackson Owens),Sony Music Entertainment,"Jun 04, 2021",6931,13,"Jul 23, 2021",-2.00,305,NZSG02100009
133,-8,I Hate U,/track?id=68085473,https://open.spotify.com/track/5dXWFMwD7I7zXsInONVl0H,SZA,I Hate U,Top Dawg Entertainment/RCA Records,"Dec 03, 2021",6922,6,"Dec 06, 2021",-0.71,125,USRC12103605
134,-3,'Till I Collapse,/track?id=15414270,https://open.spotify.com/track/4xkOaSrkexMciUUogZKVTS,"Eminem, Nate Dogg",The Eminem Show,Aftermath,"May 26, 2002",6912,73,"Mar 02, 2019",0.57,146,USIR10211066
135,3,Gangsta's Paradise,/track?id=15858008,https://open.spotify.com/track/1DIXPcTDzTj8ZMHt3PDt8p,"Coolio, L.V.",Gangsta's Paradise,"Tommy Boy Music, LLC","Oct 02, 1995",6865,115,"Feb 17, 2022",1.43,79,USTB10400128
136,-10,Beggin',/track?id=17856511,https://open.spotify.com/track/3Wrjm47oTz2sjIgck11l5e,Måneskin,Chosen,RCA Records Label,"Dec 08, 2017",6851,2,"Jul 24, 2021",-1.86,296,ITB001700846
137,9,Dance Monkey,/track?id=22955238,https://open.spotify.com/track/2N8m6CYs74qQO4mjVcXO30,Tones And I,Welcome To The Madhouse (Deluxe),Elektra (NEK),"Jul 16, 2021",6841,67,"Jul 20, 2021",0.29,263,QZES71982312
138,7,Under the Bridge,/track?id=16033465,https://open.spotify.com/track/3d9DChrdc6BOeFsbrZ3Is0,Red Hot Chili Peppers,Blood Sugar Sex Magik (Deluxe Edition),Warner Records,"Sep 24, 1991",6831,84,"Mar 08, 2019",-1.14,586,USWB19901576
139,-19,I’m Tired (with Zendaya) - Bonus Track,/track?id=73278663,https://open.spotify.com/track/6LtHYDgYHRCHoKK3snfr2w,"Labrinth, Zendaya",I’m Tired (with Zendaya) - Bonus Track,Columbia,"Feb 28, 2022",6810,13,"Mar 03, 2022",-8.00,38,USQX92200588
140,-12,Overpass Graffiti,/track?id=65243247,https://open.spotify.com/track/4btFHqumCO31GksfuBLLv3,Ed Sheeran,=,Atlantic Records UK,"Oct 29, 2021",6785,9,"Oct 29, 2021",-0.86,159,GBAHS2100673
141,18,Brown Eyed Girl,/track?id=15805428,https://open.spotify.com/track/3yrSvpt2l1xhsV9Em88Pul,Van Morrison,Blowin' Your Mind!,Columbia/Legacy,"Sep 01, 1967",6761,58,"Dec 31, 2021",-1.29,"1,152",USSM16700357
142,39,Shape of You,/track?id=12450039,https://open.spotify.com/track/7qiZfU4dY1lWllzX7mPBI3,Ed Sheeran,÷ (Deluxe),Atlantic Records UK,"Mar 03, 2017",6747,1,"Mar 07, 2017",5.86,"1,642",GBAHS1600463
143,-10,favorite crime,/track?id=43444101,https://open.spotify.com/track/5JCoSi02qi3jJeHdZXMmR8,Olivia Rodrigo,SOUR,Olivia Rodrigo PS,"May 21, 2021",6718,5,"May 30, 2021",,184,USUG12101249
144,-2,Get Into It (Yuh),/track?id=49661835,https://open.spotify.com/track/0W6I02J9xcqK8MtSeosEXb,Doja Cat,Planet Her,Kemosabe Records/RCA Records,"Jun 25, 2021",6703,15,"Aug 25, 2021",2.43,255,USRC12101535
145,-8,love nwantiti (ah ah ah),/track?id=25088483,https://open.spotify.com/track/2Xr1dTzJee307rmrkt8c0g,CKay,CKay The First,Chocolate City Music,"Aug 30, 2019",6665,10,"Oct 03, 2021",0.29,207,QMEU31910213
146,2,Ms. Jackson,/track?id=15483832,https://open.spotify.com/track/0I3q5fE6wg7LIfHGngUTnV,Outkast,Stankonia,Arista/LaFace Records,"Oct 31, 2000",6646,124,"Mar 12, 2022",0.71,111,USLF20000357
147,-18,Dancing On My Own,/track?id=14483852,https://open.spotify.com/track/2BOqDYLOJBiMOXShCV1neZ,Calum Scott,Only Human (Deluxe),Capitol Records (US1A),"Mar 09, 2018",6638,96,"Jun 29, 2020",-2.00,901,UK6KW1500205
148,-4,Tennessee Whiskey,/track?id=15933319,https://open.spotify.com/track/3fqwjXwUGN6vbzIwvyFMhx,Chris Stapleton,Traveller,Mercury Nashville,"May 04, 2015",6634,76,"Dec 31, 2021",-0.86,"1,426",USUM71418088
149,13,Bohemian Rhapsody - Remastered 2011,/track?id=13066583,https://open.spotify.com/track/4u7EnebtmKWzUH433cf5Qv,Queen,A Night At The Opera (2011 Remaster),EMI,"Nov 21, 1975",6620,39,"Apr 20, 2019",0.57,"1,009",GBUM71029604
150,23,California Love - Original Version,/track?id=15892932,https://open.spotify.com/track/3ia3dJETSOllPsv3LJkE35,"2Pac, Roger, Dr. Dre",Greatest Hits,2Pac Greatest Hits,"Jan 01, 1998",6613,56,"Feb 16, 2022",0.86,52,USUG10702628
151,-4,One Dance,/track?id=15194415,https://open.spotify.com/track/1zi7xx7UVEFkmKfv06H8x0,"Drake, WizKid, Kyla",Views,Cash Money Records/Young Money Ent./Universal Rec.,"May 06, 2016",6582,140,"Jul 13, 2018",1.29,133,USCM51600028
152,35,Thinking out Loud,/track?id=12449356,https://open.spotify.com/track/1Slwb6dOYkBlWal1PGtnNg,Ed Sheeran,x (Wembley Edition),Atlantic Records UK,"Jan 01, 2013",6579,38,"Mar 29, 2018",2.00,"1,442",GBAHS1400099
153,-2,Heartbreak Anniversary,/track?id=28541554,https://open.spotify.com/track/3FAJ6O0NOHQV8Mc5Ri6ENp,Giveon,TAKE TIME,Epic/Not So Fast,"Mar 27, 2020",6561,2,"Mar 14, 2021",2.14,416,USSM12000998
154,25,Jah Rastafari,/track?id=13708512,https://open.spotify.com/track/3XJy1qvLFMV42kL0lf73Po,1814,Jah Rydem,Patu Colbert,"Jan 01, 2008",6527,50,"Dec 26, 2021",1.14,375,NZEH00800003
155,23,Slice of Heaven,/track?id=13712816,https://open.spotify.com/track/4qVIORNqKvlFvE4HMgnvVC,"Dave Dobbyn, Herbs",Loyal,"Dobworld Limited, Thom Music","May 01, 1988",6522,27,"Dec 31, 2021",-5.57,551,NZSG00600072
156,8,Ni**as In Paris,/track?id=15920975,https://open.spotify.com/track/4Li2WHPkuyCdtmokzW2007,"JAY-Z, Kanye West",Watch The Throne (Deluxe),Roc Nation/RocAFella/IDJ,"Aug 08, 2011",6509,101,"Aug 05, 2016",2.57,335,USUM71111621
157,29,All Falls Down,/track?id=15234674,https://open.spotify.com/track/5SkRLpaGtvYPhw02vZhQQ9,"Kanye West, Syleena Johnson",The College Dropout,Roc-A-Fella,"Feb 10, 2004",6485,122,"Mar 02, 2022",-3.00,45,USDJ20301703
158,-6,Take Me To Church,/track?id=13198846,https://open.spotify.com/track/3dYD57lRAUcMHufyqn9GcI,Hozier,Hozier,Universal-Island Records Ltd.,"Jul 20, 2014",6473,110,"Mar 14, 2021",3.14,373,IEACJ1300031
159,-9,Circles,/track?id=25021708,https://open.spotify.com/track/21jGcNKet2qwijlDFuPiPb,Post Malone,Hollywood's Bleeding,Republic Records,"Sep 06, 2019",6469,2,"Sep 16, 2019",-1.43,930,USUM71915699
160,11,Forgot About Dre,/track?id=15417070,https://open.spotify.com/track/7iXF2W9vKmDoGAhlHdpyIa,"Dr. Dre, Eminem",2001,Aftermath,"Nov 16, 1999",6456,62,"Feb 15, 2022",-0.14,43,USIR19915077
161,-12,3 Nights,/track?id=21807733,https://open.spotify.com/track/0uI7yAKUf52Cn7y3sYyjiX,Dominic Fike,"Don't Forget About Me, Demos",Columbia,"Oct 16, 2018",6452,69,"Jan 09, 2020",-0.43,401,USQX91802455
162,-30,lovely (with Khalid),/track?id=19088585,https://open.spotify.com/track/0u2P5u6lvoDfwTYjAADbn4,"Billie Eilish, Khalid",lovely (with Khalid),Darkroom,"Apr 19, 2018",6445,3,"Jun 10, 2018",-1.14,"1,112",USUM71804190
163,-3,One Right Now (with The Weeknd),/track?id=65751614,https://open.spotify.com/track/00Blm7zeNqgYLPtW6zg8cj,"Post Malone, The Weeknd",One Right Now,Republic Records,"Nov 05, 2021",6445,11,"Nov 08, 2021",0.29,149,USUM72120404
164,6,Empire State Of Mind,/track?id=15452836,https://open.spotify.com/track/2igwFfvr1OAGX9SKDCPBwO,"JAY-Z, Alicia Keys",The Blueprint 3,Roc Nation / Jay-Z,"Sep 08, 2009",6444,164,"Apr 07, 2022",2.86,23,USJZ10900031
165,0,Godzilla (feat. Juice WRLD),/track?id=28213841,https://open.spotify.com/track/7FIWs0pqAYbP91WWM0vlTQ,"Eminem, Juice WRLD",Music To Be Murdered By,Shady/Aftermath/Interscope Records,"Jan 17, 2020",6436,2,"Jan 23, 2020",1.43,565,USUM72000788
166,-11,You Right,/track?id=50617036,https://open.spotify.com/track/0k4d5YPDr1r7FX77VdqWez,"Doja Cat, The Weeknd",Planet Her,Kemosabe Records/RCA Records,"Jun 25, 2021",6431,8,"Jun 27, 2021",0.71,276,USRC12100544
167,-1,Substance,/track?id=18463956,https://open.spotify.com/track/0MoQI1EZGSHLhd5UBdxPol,03 Greedo,The Wolf of Grape Street,Alamo,"Mar 09, 2018",6420,112,"Mar 07, 2022",0.71,48,USUYG1183222
168,29,Hey Ya!,/track?id=15049297,https://open.spotify.com/track/2PpruBYCo4H7WOBJ7Q2EwM,Outkast,Speakerboxxx/The Love Below,Arista,"Jan 01, 2003",6416,54,"Dec 31, 2017",,81,USAR10300924
169,0,It Was A Good Day,/track?id=15599388,https://open.spotify.com/track/2qOm7ukLyHUXWyR4ZWLwxA,Ice Cube,The Predator,Priority Records,"Nov 17, 1992",6415,118,"Feb 17, 2022",-2.43,61,USPO19250006
170,14,Sultans Of Swing,/track?id=12761361,https://open.spotify.com/track/37Tmv4NnfQeb0ZgUC4fOJj,Dire Straits,Dire Straits,EMI,"Oct 07, 1978",6408,83,"Jan 29, 2022",-3.14,461,GBF089601041
171,-17,Yellow,/track?id=12521939,https://open.spotify.com/track/3AJwUDP919kvQ9QcozQPxg,Coldplay,Parachutes,Parlophone UK,"Jul 10, 2000",6406,93,"May 09, 2021",-4.43,379,GBAYE0000267
172,-11,Good Days,/track?id=32400834,https://open.spotify.com/track/3YJJjQPAbDT7mGpX3WtQ9A,SZA,Good Days,Top Dawg Entertainment/RCA Records,"Dec 25, 2020",6395,2,"Feb 09, 2021",1.29,458,USRC12004189
173,3,Mood (feat. iann dior),/track?id=30361159,https://open.spotify.com/track/4jPy3l0RUwlUI9T5XHBW2m,"24kGoldn, iann dior",El Dorado,Records/Columbia,"Mar 26, 2021",6393,24,"Mar 28, 2021",-2.29,375,USQX92003025
174,0,They Don't Know,/track?id=13708248,https://open.spotify.com/track/2lLbW1PLYdcg7pWK8vRVIu,"Savage, Aaradhna",Moonshine,Frequency,"Jan 01, 2005",6386,79,"Feb 24, 2022",0.29,251,NZDR00500013
175,-17,Classic,/track?id=15790670,https://open.spotify.com/track/6FE2iI43OZnszFLuLtvvmg,MKTO,MKTO,Columbia/M2V,"Jan 01, 2012",6355,78,"Oct 28, 2021",-0.86,260,USSM11301446
176,17,"Rocket Man (I Think It's Going To Be A Long, Long Time)",/track?id=12483467,https://open.spotify.com/track/3gdewACMIVMEWVbyb8O9sY,Elton John,Honky Chateau,EMI,"May 19, 1972",6351,31,"Jun 02, 2019",-4.57,"1,328",GBAMB7200006
177,-10,Iris,/track?id=16032306,https://open.spotify.com/track/6Qyc6fS4DsZjB2mRW9DsQs,The Goo Goo Dolls,Dizzy up the Girl,Warner Records,"Sep 11, 1998",6324,119,"Mar 31, 2022",-8.29,82,USWB19800160
178,-21,Save Your Tears,/track?id=28793673,https://open.spotify.com/track/5QO79kh1waicV47BqGRL3g,The Weeknd,After Hours,Republic Records,"Mar 20, 2020",6304,16,"Feb 18, 2021",2.57,211,USUG12000658
179,11,Promiscuous,/track?id=15902731,https://open.spotify.com/track/2gam98EZKrF9XuOkU13ApN,"Nelly Furtado, Timbaland",Loose,Mosley / Geffen,"Jan 01, 2006",6300,77,"Oct 29, 2020",-0.29,283,USUM70603473
180,19,The Next Episode,/track?id=15417071,https://open.spotify.com/track/4LwU4Vp6od3Sb08CsP99GC,"Dr. Dre, Snoop Dogg",2001,Aftermath,"Nov 16, 1999",6263,47,"Feb 16, 2022",-0.29,48,USIR19915078
181,13,Sure Thing,/track?id=15447187,https://open.spotify.com/track/0JXXNGljqupsJaZsgSbMZV,Miguel,All I Want Is You,Jive,"Nov 26, 2010",6252,66,"Jun 02, 2021",,319,USJI10800160
182,-14,Adore You,/track?id=27599120,https://open.spotify.com/track/3jjujdWJ72nww5eGnfs2E7,Harry Styles,Fine Line,Columbia,"Dec 13, 2019",6234,5,"Dec 16, 2019",,581,USSM11912588
183,-17,Always on My Mind,/track?id=13707988,https://open.spotify.com/track/19cxRMqCzpYNU4wXcMj8jA,Tiki Taane,"Past, Present, Future",Dirty Dub,"Jan 01, 2007",6202,55,"Dec 26, 2021",-4.00,650,NZDD00700017
184,16,No Scrubs,/track?id=15484595,https://open.spotify.com/track/1KGi9sZVMeszgZOWivFpxs,TLC,Fanmail,Arista/LaFace Records,"Feb 23, 1999",6193,99,"Sep 15, 2016",2.00,211,USLF29900479
185,-22,Bound 2,/track?id=15927278,https://open.spotify.com/track/3sNVsP50132BTNlImLx70i,Kanye West,Yeezus,Rock The World/IDJ/Kanye/LP6,"Jun 18, 2013",6162,156,"Mar 21, 2022",1.14,24,USUM71307523
186,7,Perfect,/track?id=12450042,https://open.spotify.com/track/0tgVpDi06FyKpA1z0VMD4v,Ed Sheeran,÷ (Deluxe),Atlantic Records UK,"Mar 03, 2017",6150,6,"Mar 06, 2017",,"1,679",GBAHS1700024
187,-5,Martin & Gina,/track?id=29427847,https://open.spotify.com/track/1VLtjHwRWOVJiE5Py7JxoQ,Polo G,THE GOAT,Columbia,"May 15, 2020",6148,52,"Apr 12, 2021",-5.29,512,USQX92002595
188,-21,Somebody That I Used To Know,/track?id=11030776,https://open.spotify.com/track/1qDrWA6lyx8cLECdZE7TV7,"Gotye, Kimbra",Making Mirrors,Universal-Island Records Ltd.,"Jan 01, 2011",6137,166,"Apr 21, 2021",,25,AUZS21100040
189,-36,chaotic,/track?id=78044388,https://open.spotify.com/track/2bdqU7C4softKNcMYDFi96,Tate McRae,chaotic,RCA Records Label,"Mar 25, 2022",6129,42,"Mar 27, 2022",-13.43,12,USRC12102862
190,5,Afterglow,/track?id=12613367,https://open.spotify.com/track/6LW3Z1GqbL78TIjfDyg4zp,"Wilkinson, Becky Hill",Lazers Not Included,EMI,"Jan 01, 2013",6123,56,"May 13, 2021",,360,GBBZH1391803
191,-11,Help Me Out - Bonus Track,/track?id=31658458,https://open.spotify.com/track/7caFVygWyV6WfNcn5RrXDQ,"Kings, Sons Of Zion",RAPLIST (Fly Edition),Arch Angel Records,"May 21, 2021",6110,37,"May 21, 2021",-1.71,275,NZAC12000002
192,-7,Tropical,/track?id=17951282,https://open.spotify.com/track/3qIxnOusGoTpHvNVMLHscw,SL,Tropical,Independent,"Dec 26, 2017",6104,172,"Apr 04, 2022",,5,GBLFP1797885
193,-4,Heartless,/track?id=15911299,https://open.spotify.com/track/4EWCNWgDS8707fNSZ1oaA5,Kanye West,808s & Heartbreak,Roc-A-Fella,"Nov 24, 2008",6098,161,"Mar 16, 2022",0.86,18,USUM70840511
194,-11,Listen to the Music,/track?id=16010077,https://open.spotify.com/track/7Ar4G7Ci11gpt6sfH9Cgz5,The Doobie Brothers,Toulouse Street,Warner Records,"Jan 01, 1972",6081,78,"Jan 29, 2022",-1.29,851,USWB10000626
195,-23,Location (feat. Burna Boy),/track?id=22554309,https://open.spotify.com/track/3z4CGd63tpUn9a6oQSG0CI,"Dave, Burna Boy",PSYCHODRAMA,Neighbourhood,"Mar 08, 2019",6063,160,"Apr 04, 2022",-1.14,7,GBUM71900578
196,-9,Dancing in the Moonlight,/track?id=12549819,https://open.spotify.com/track/3Fzlg5r1IjhLk2qRw667od,Toploader,Onka's Big Moka,Sony Soho Square,"Jan 01, 2000",6052,88,"Dec 31, 2020",,263,GBBBL9902165
197,-41,Falling,/track?id=27651731,https://open.spotify.com/track/1ZMiCix7XSAbfAJlEZWMCp,Harry Styles,Fine Line,Columbia,"Dec 13, 2019",6049,24,"Dec 13, 2019",,617,USSM11912590
198,-7,Before You Go,/track?id=27430934,https://open.spotify.com/track/2gMXnyrvIjhVBUZwvLZDMP,Lewis Capaldi,Divinely Uninspired To A Hellish Extent (Extended Edition),Vertigo Berlin,"Nov 22, 2019",6048,11,"Feb 20, 2020",-0.86,835,DEUM71905868
199,-4,"Surface Pressure - From ""Encanto""/Soundtrack Version",/track?id=66944652,https://open.spotify.com/track/6K5ph5mq1qprHae3TrgTj5,Jessica Darrow,"Surface Pressure (From ""Encanto"")","UMG Recordings, Inc.","Jan 27, 2022",6026,20,"Feb 06, 2022",-8.29,70,USWD12112914
200,-4,Just the Way You Are,/track?id=15084776,https://open.spotify.com/track/7BqBn9nzAq8spo5e7cZ0dJ,Bruno Mars,Doo-Wops & Hooligans,Atlantic Records,"Oct 05, 2010",6022,116,"Apr 19, 2021",,127,USAT21001269
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please verify the indentation of the code that you posted.

Comment: Please show a sample of perhaps 50 lines from your CSV files.

Comment: CSV example now there

Comment: It's worth noting that these data cannot be CSV-exported without a premium subscription to ChartMetric.

Comment: I stupidly copied it from an excel, in there as an actual CSV now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid Selenium if possible, but given that the website requires authentication it might be nontrivial. That said: you aren't using it other than the import; why?

I also don't understand why you're merging to an excel file. Your report - in intent, though perhaps not in implementation - only cares about the last 24 hours; so why would you merge and load?

Your repeated in-place `drop`s will be less efficient than directly loading the CSV and specifying in `usecols` only the columns you want to keep.

Rather than coercing `Change=New` to 99999, it's simpler to include the `New` comparison as part of your filtration predicate.

Avoid using `iloc` for named columns. Just use the column names.

Your quite long copy-and-paste has effectively unrolled a loop that would just write out the top *n* rows of the dataframe. This repetition should go away. One easy way to look at the top few rows of a `DataFrame` is `head()`.

You've hard-coded for Outlook. More portably, multiple mail clients should be able to read `.eml` files whose content can be produced by the Python built-in `email` modules; so consider doing that (even if it's a first step toward using Outlook anyway). For Outlook you might need to [set an `X-Unsent` header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60117723/how-to-create-an-eml-file-as-outlook-draft-email-with-django-emailmessage).

Don't do this:

```
df["Release Date"].str.split(', ').str[1]
```

Instead, load this column as an actual Pandas timestamp.

### Suggested

This suggestion covers loading, filtration and email generation, but not web download or Excel.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formataddr

import pandas as pd


def load_csv(filename: str = 'Spotify Daily Top 200.csv') -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.read_csv(
        filename,
        parse_dates=['Peak Date', 'Release Date'],
        usecols=[
            'Rank', 'Change', 'Track', 'External Link', 'Artist', 'Release Date',
            'Streams', 'Peak Position', 'Peak Date', 'Total Days on Chart',
        ],
    )


def row_to_html(row: pd.Series) -> str:
    return f'''
{row.Artist} -
<a href="{row['External Link']}">{row.Track}</a>&emsp;|
First released in {row['Release Date'].year}.
{row.Streams} streams in the past 24 hours,
up {row.Change} places to #{row.Rank}<br/>
'''


def row_to_plain(row: pd.Series) -> str:
    return f'''
{row.Artist} - {row.Track}
First released in {row['Release Date'].year}.
{row.Streams} streams in the past 24 hours,
up {row.Change} places to #{row.Rank}
'''


def render_html(df: pd.DataFrame) -> str:
    head = '''
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family:calibri;font-size:30px">TODAY'S SPIKEY SONGS</h1>
<i><h4 style="font-family:calibri-light;font-size:12px;color:red">THIS IS AN AUTOMATED EMAIL</h4></i>
<p style="font-family:calibri light">
'''

    rows = df.apply(row_to_html, axis=1).str.cat()

    foot = '''
  </p>
</body>
</html>'''

    return head + rows + foot


def render_plain(df: pd.DataFrame) -> str:
    rows = df.apply(row_to_plain, axis=1).str.cat()
    return "TODAY'S SPIKEY SONGS:\n\n" + rows


def filter_csv(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return df[
        (df.Streams >= 7_000)
        & (
            (df.Change >= 5) | (df.Change == 'New')
        )
        & (df['Release Date'].dt.year <= 2021)
        & (df.Rank <= 100)
    ]


def make_message(df: pd.DataFrame) -> bytes:
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = 'Spotify Daily Spike'
    msg['From'] = formataddr(('Spikebot', 'spikebot@myfancydomain.nz'))
    msg['To'] = formataddr(('Ross F', 'rossf@myfancydomain.nz'))

    msg.attach(MIMEText(render_plain(df), 'plain'))
    msg.attach(MIMEText(render_html(df), 'html'))

    return msg.as_bytes()


def main() -> None:
    df = filter_csv(load_csv())
    print(f'{len(df)} songs returned')

    n_songs = int(input('How many songs to send: '))
    df = df.head(n_songs)

    with open('spikey.eml', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(make_message(df))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Output

As shown in Evolution:

[image: email screenshot]

Comment: Wow - I knew I had something that was too long, that is so much shorter!
One question I have, it creates an .eml file - how would I best get that to open in Outlook to be able to send?

Comment: You may need to set a header - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60117723/how-to-create-an-eml-file-as-outlook-draft-email-with-django-emailmessage - but otherwise it should be trivial